# Is .NET Thread.Sleep affected by DST (or system time) changes?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, kernel, clock

i'm not sure how the Windows kernel handles Thread timing ...

i'm speaking about DST and any other event that affects the time of day on Windows boxes.

for example, Thread [.Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) will block a thread from zero to [infinite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timeout.infinite.aspx) milliseconds.

if the kernel uses the same "clock" as that used for time of day, then when

(a) someone *manually* changes the time of day, or
(b) some synchronization to a time server changes the time of day, or
(c) Daylight Saving Time begins or ends and the system has been configured to respond to these two DST events,
*et cetera*,

are sleeping threads in any way affected? i.e., does the kernel handle such events in such a way that the programmer need do nothing?

**N.B.**:  for *non-critical* applications, this is likely a *who cares?* situation.

For *critical* applications, knowing the answer to this  question is important because of the *possibility* that one must program for such exception conditions.

thank you

edit:  i thought of a simple test which i've run in [LINQPad 4](http://www.linqpad.net/).

the test involved putting the thread to sleep, starting a manual timer at approximately the same time as the thread was put to sleep, and then (a) moving the time ahead one hour, then for the second test, moving the time back two hours ... in both tests, the period of sleep was **not** affected.

Bottom line:  with Thread.Sleep, there is no need to worry about events that affect the time of day.

here's the trivial c# code:

```
Int32   secondsToSleep;
String  seconds; 
Boolean inputOkay;
Console.WriteLine("How many seconds?");
seconds   = Console.ReadLine();
inputOkay = Int32.TryParse(seconds, out secondsToSleep); 
if (inputOkay)
{
    Console.WriteLine("sleeping for {0} second(s)", secondsToSleep);
    Thread.Sleep(secondsToSleep * 1000);
    Console.WriteLine("i am awake!");
}
else Console.WriteLine("invalid input:  [{0}]", seconds);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, `Thread.Sleep` is not affected. The kernel furthermore keeps time in UTC exclusively. Time zones and DST are just layered above that.

Comment: To expand on this a little, `Thread.Sleep` is not affected because internally the kernel uses the tick count (the number of milliseconds since the system booted) for this sort of job and there's no way to manually adjust the tick count.  (Actually it's a bit more complicated but the fine detail isn't important.)

Comment: @ Joey thnx; Harry Johnston has commented that the kernal uses the tick count ... so would UTC even be involved?

Comment: @ Harry Johnston thnx; just curious, where is this documented? this was my suspicion but i don't know where it's documented. Given that the [tick count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx) is reset on system start, then it would almost certainly be left alone by any (re)setting of the time of day.

Comment: Harry, wouldn't Windows use 100-ns intervals for ticks? Those are used almost everywhere else in the system as sub-second precision timestamps, actually. Just curious; I have no actual idea ;-). gerryLowry: No, the actual time and date (as well as UTC) would likely not be involved in any way. That was just a rebuttal of your theory in the question, basically saying that even if it would be used it would make no difference.

Comment: @ Joey your explanation, for me, was unclear ... you may want to edit it as per your recent comment.  your answer is correct, i.e., `Thread.Sleep` is *not* affected. much appreciated.

Comment: @ Harry Johnston your embellishment of Joey's answer was very useful to me ... for that reason i've voted it up ... for me, if you could point me towards the documentation, that would help satisfy my curiousity ... while the "fine detail" may not be important, i'd still enjoy reading it.  thnx